# How to set minimum and maximum fields of a custom ID property using Python

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I have created a custom property and want to set a minimum and a maximum for it through python; I tried to make it using `bpy.ops.wm.properties_edit` but it didn't work,so how can I edit a custom property with Python?

Here is how I defined my property:

```
bpy.data.objects[name of my object]['name of my property'] = 2
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the property? Or is this a property you created via the UI?

Comment: @RayMairlot bpy.data.objects[name of my object]['name of my property'] = 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you do to set min to 0 and max to 500, the soft_min and soft_max is optional and is only for dragging in gui:

```
ob = bpy.data.objects[name_of_my_object]

# this is a dictionary containing IDprops settings
# this creates it and erases it:
ob["_RNA_UI"] = {}

# add properties settings like this:
ob["_RNA_UI"]['name_of_my_property'] = {"min":0.0,
                                        "max": 500.0,
                                        "soft_min":0.0,
                                        "soft_max":500.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

BLender 3.1 method.

```
lod_prop = "LOD"
control_object[lod_prop] = 1
id_props = control_object.id_properties_ui(lod_prop)
id_props.update(min=0,
                max=2,
                )
control_object.property_overridable_library_set('["LOD"]', True)
```